# A different way to manage sessions

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm working in a cookie-less way to manage sessions in my project (expressjs), keeping all session data server side and using a token at client side (previously generated by the server) to validate the session on every request.

A new token will be created on user login and kept hide somewhere in the page, then, on every request this token will be written to the request header and validated server side. at this point server will search for the token in a session store, lets say redis, and get the session data if the token is found or respond with a message of session expired otherwise.

There are some things i'm considering for this:

- Redis keys are created on user login with a settled expiration.
- Every time session data is found in redis i have to 'touch' the key
  so expiration time gets postponed.
- Token will be validated along side with the ip address of the client so can't be used by other person.

My question is **if this is can be considered a secure way to work with**, and if there is anything i'm missing here. Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is pretty much the same as using cookies with redis session store, except you are using custom header and not cookie header. So yes, this is as much as secure.

Comment: Define "kept hidden somewhere in the page". Also, it sounds like you're trying to reinvent session cookies, with the added disadvantage that any security measures your browser might take with cookies are circumvented.

Comment: I meant to put an input hidden somewhere, mm you got a point, but what are the security measures browser might take that could affect my method? considering i am not doing weird things like going from one domain to another

Comment: @RenzoCortez cookies can be classified `httpOnly`, which means that they can't be read by JS (and therefore, XSS attacks). Hidden inputs don't get a similar protection.

Answer (score 0):

OK, cookies are required for storing session. Express does it the ideal way.

In express **session**(not **cookiesession**) it is completely stored at the server, only a key is sent to the client. The whole session is serialized to a key which is then sent. I assume you want that user cannot tamper with the session cookies. You can use httponly cookies to prevent tampering. They are only handled by browser and cannot be accessed by user. This prevents cookie theft or session hijacking. You can enable httponly cookies with:

```
 app.use(express.session({cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true}, secret:'password'}));
```

Still you should use some encryption to prevent eavesdropping of cookies. Use `secure : true` for that. You can also mention where you want to store the session with redis, mongo or simply in memory.

The request token validation that you mention is a technique commonly used to prevent Cross-site request forgery. It keeps changing the token dynamically to keep user from getting the token. You can use this in express with [csrf](http://expressjs.com/api.html#csrf) middleware.

```
app.use(express.csrf())
```

IP matching will not work as IP of user can change over time.